# How do we change the block size in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

What  is the  difference between  Cloudera CDH3 cluster and Cloudera CDH4 cluster

What is the default  hdfs block size in CDH3

What is the default hdfs block size in CDH4

How to change the hdfs block size in cloudera CDH3 and CDH4 cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the hdfs block size in the hdfs-site.xml file. The default is generally 64 or 128 MB, but you can change it in the mentioned file, by changing the `dfs.blocksize` property:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>SIZE_IN_BYTES</value> 
</property>
```

Bear in mind that the value you write must be in bytes, so 128MB for example would be 134217728 Bytes.